# Use of PHP Return vs Else in include files

Tags: php, include, return, conditional-statements

I understand that both of the below are valid, however I was wondering which was considered the best solution.

I have some code in an included file. If certain conditions are met, I would like to stop execution of the remaining code in the included file and return to the calling file.

**Example 1** has the following code in the included file:

```
$error = false;
// Some code here that can trigger $error = true

if ($error) {
    return; // return to calling file
}

// More code below, only to be executed if $error = false
```

**Example 2** has the following code in the included file:

```
$error = false;
// Some code here that can trigger $error = true

if (!$error) {
    // Execute remaining code within the conditional statement
}

// Return to the calling file
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both options are same,You can either option you are comfortable with

Comment: I use the former one because I think when there are many `if` statements, no `else` is needed.

Comment: doesnt the second statement mean, if NOT $error which would execute only if $error is true? and the first statement meaning if error is false then execute.

Comment: I use the switch statement a lot when all of my values are $error myself; however, If there are many if statements it is best to use a elseif instead of just else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer **Example 1**, because the early return pattern leads to less indented code. If you have more than one check like the one in **Example 2**, you will end with heavily indented code:

```
$error = false;
// Some code here that can trigger $error = true

if (!$error) {
    // Execute remaining code within the conditional statement

    // Some more code here that can trigger $error = true

    if (!$error) {
        // Execute remaining code within the conditional statement
    }
}

// Return to the calling file
```

which forces you to remember unnecessarily "this block is in the successful branch of the `if`".

Answer (score 0):

There's virtually no difference, but I use the **1-st approach** for one simple reason: I want the main code body to be more visible, not hidden under tones of brackets and intends.

Answer (score 0):

Include is NOT the same as calling a function, so it gives no meaning talking about to "*stop execution of the remaining code in the included file and return to the calling file*"

To include something in PHP just means that the text from one file is put into a specific location in another file.